# Как сделать вывод в полностью новую страницу, а не в какой-то контейнер на странице?

Tags: ajax, вывод

Нашел на просторах интернета вот такой скрипт для сортировки товаров на странице:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sort span").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#fon").css({'display':'block'});
        $("#load").fadeIn(1000,function () {
            $.ajax({
                url:'/?pages=product',
                data:'sort_id='+id,
                type:'get',
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#prod_content").html(html).hide().fadeIn(2000);
                    $("#fon").css({'display':'none'});
                    $("#load").fadeOut(1000);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Почти со всем разобрался, но не могу понять только одного: когда идет вывод ответа от сервера, то в данном коде указано, что вывод осуществлять в блок с `id=prod_content`.

Как сделать так, чтобы вывод ответа осуществлялся просто как полностью новая страница, а не в какой-то контейнер на странице?

Comment: так для этого ajax тогда не нужен. Это банально со страницы сразу прямиком с формы отправляй данные и всё

Comment: @Grundy а `что бы` Пушкин редактировать будет?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что-то я его не заметил :-)

Comment: Спасибо! Понял, что реально зря заморачивался с аяксом, можно было и так все написать! =)) Нупчик

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно же, использовать селектор body:

```
...
$("body").html(html).hide().fadeIn(2000);
...
```